# Find number of occurrences of word under cursor

Tags: vim

I've enjoyed using <kbd>#</kbd> to highlight and search for a word (variable) but I would love if I could hit a single command that would simply tell me how many occurrences are in the current file.  I've found the following

```
:%s/dns_name_change_flag/&/gn
```

But that's too much typing.  Is there anyway to maybe map the above one-liner to use the word under cursor?

Comment: Note that `#` searches backwards and `*` is the forward version. (I mention it since it seems odd to mention the reverse version.)

Comment: Thanks for the note ... It's amazing I never caught the direction piece.  With wrap, I just kept tapping away.  I'm sure in 20 years I'll still be learning little tricks with Vim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to do this without `execute`. The following maps `F5` to count occurrences of the word under the cursor using `<cword>` and word boundary patterns (`\\<` and `\\>`):

```
:map <f5> :execute ":%s@\\<" . expand("<cword>") . "\\>\@&@gn"<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:map <F2> "zyiw:exe "%s/".@z."//gn"<CR>
```

add this line (without the ":") to your .vimrc and F2 will be mapped every time you start vim.

It yanks the 'inner word' to the z register and then performs a search in the whole buffer outputting the number of appearances.

This approach differs to [the one given by Thor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11492536/1521347) in that way, that it also counts appearances of the word that are not a word themselves, but only part of a word. For example: **looking for 'an' will also count 'and'**.

---

This might be helpful too:

"A quick way to list all occurrences of the word under the cursor it to type **[I** (which displays each line containing the current keyword, in this file and in included files when using a language such as C)."

source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_count

Answer (score 1):

#### Map Execute to Grep

You can map a sequence to an external grep command. For example:

```
:nmap fg :execute '!fgrep --count <cword> %'<CR>
```

This maps a normal-mode command to <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>. The command will run *fgrep* on the current file in an external process, counting the instances of the word under the cursor.

#### Minor Caveat

This operates on the current file, not the current buffer. You need to make sure the file is written to disk (e.g. `:write`) before the word count will be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a plugin for that: [SearchPosition](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634); it provides mappings for the current search pattern and current word / selection, and also lists where the matches occur:

```
1 match after cursor in this line, 8 following, 2 in previous lines;
total 10 for /\<SearchPosition\>/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:nmap <Leader>* *<C-o>:%s///gn<CR><C-o>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that does not change search register `@/`

```
fun! CountWordFunction()
    try
        let l:win_view = winsaveview()
        exec "%s/" . expand("<cword>") . "//gn"
    finally
        call winrestview(l:win_view)
    endtry
endfun
command! -nargs=0 CountWord :call CountWordFunction()
nnoremap <F3> :CountWord<CR>
```

If you alredy have searched for the word you can just type

```
:%~n
```